# Excel formula to check each two cells neighbours have a match

Tags: excel, formulas

I need to check if (each) cell in column A is having a match in column B, Example as below:

Column A is phone numbers list, column B is messages list ( which will contain a text and one phone number "it should be the same phone number as the one on column A") Now i need to make sure that phone number on A1 is the same phone number that occur on B1,etc. I don't know how to check if A1 phone number is the same phone number on B1 ? or not, and apply the check for all cells in the column? it should show me only if it is not the same, i tried every things and i could not know how to do it.

Comment: In C1: `=IF(ISERR(FIND(A1,B1)),FIND(A1,B1),"")`

Answer (score 0):

In C1 try this formula.

```
=if(isnumber(find(A1, B1)), "", "not the same")
```

Fill down as necessary to check every phone number in column A with the message in column b. A quick way to quickly fill down is to double-click the small black square *drag handle* in the lower right corner of the selected cell.